# Cache NSView Context

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, cgcontext

I'm trying to store NSView Current Context and draw it later to NSView again. I was wondering what is the fastest and most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can draw your content to an `NSImage` and just redraw the image later, but you need to invalidate the cache when needed (this depends on what your view does).

Example:

```
@interface SOCacheView : NSView

@end

@implementation SOCacheView
{
    NSImage *_cache;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    if (!_cache) [self prepareImage];

    [_cache drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint fromRect:self.bounds operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
}

- (void)prepareImage
{
    _cache = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:self.bounds.size];
    [_cache lockFocus];

    // do the drawing here...

    [[NSColor blueColor] setFill];
    NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(0, 0, NSWidth(self.bounds)/2, NSHeight(self.bounds)));
    [[NSColor redColor] setFill];
    NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(NSWidth(self.bounds)/2, 0, NSWidth(self.bounds)/2, NSHeight(self.bounds)));

    [_cache unlockFocus];
}
```

To invalidate the cached drawing, just set `_cache` to `nil`.

[Here's a sample project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/452482/stackoverflow/Cache%20View.zip) for you to play with